# C++ weird async behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost

Note that I'm using boost async, due to the lack of threading classes support in MinGW.

So, I wanted to send a packet every 5 seconds and decided to use `boost::async` (`std::async`) for this purpose.

This is the function I use to send the packet (this is actually copying to the buffer and sending in the main application loop - nvm - it's working fine outside async method!)

```
m_sendBuf = new char[1024]; // allocate buffer

[..]

bool CNetwork::Send(const void* sourceBuffer, size_t size) {
    size_t bufDif = m_sendBufSize - m_sendInBufPos;
    if (size > bufDif) {
        return false;
    }

    memcpy(m_sendBuf + m_sendInBufPos, sourceBuffer, size);
    m_sendInBufPos += size;
    return true;
}
```

Packet sending code:

```
struct TestPacket {
    unsigned char type;
    int code;
};


void SendPacket() {
    TestPacket myPacket{};

    myPacket.type = 10;
    myPacket.code = 1234;

    Send(&TestPacket, sizeof(myPacket));
}
```

Async code:

```
void StartPacketSending() {
    SendPacket();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{5});
    StartPacketSending(); // Recursive endless call
}

boost::async(boost::launch::async, &StartPacketSending);
```

Alright. So the thing is, when I call `SendPacket()` from the async method, received packet is malformed on the server side and the data is different than specified. This doesn't happend when called outside the async call.

What is going on here? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Unrelated: "due to the lack of threading classes support in MinGW." Your copy of MinGW must be pretty darn old. Have you tried adding -std=c++0x or -std=c++11 to your command line?

Comment: `// Recursive endless call` why recurse? You will run out of Automatic storage eventually.

Comment: @user4581301 Because I want it to run forever. I think it's better than having infinite loop.

Comment: It won't run forever. Most likely end is the program runs off the end of the stack and the program crashes. An infinite loop is a far more gentile and stable solution.

Comment: It will run forever or until stack space is exhausted, whichever comes first. @user4581301, I'm pretty certain you meant gentle rather than gentile (non-Jewish) yes? Probably not a good idea putting "solution" in *any* sentence involving someone's Jewishness :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Oik! Actually, I meant genteel: Elegant. Refined.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have my head wrapped around what you are doing here. You are loading all unsent in to buffer in one thread and then flushing it in a different thread. Even thought the packets aren't overlapping (assuming they are consumed quickly enough), you still to synchronize all the shared data.

`m_sendBuf`, `m_sendInPos`, and `m_sendBufSize` are all being read from the main thread, likely while memcpy or your buffer size logic is running. I suspect you will have to use a proper queue to get your program to work as intended in the long run, but try protecting those variables with a mutex.

Also as other commenters have pointed out, infinite recursion is not supported in C++, but that probably does not contribute to your malformed packets.